# Follow of starting symbol

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Given Grammar is

E->T+E

E->T

T->i

I want to know the Follow(E)=?.

My approach:

Approach 1

follow(E) ={$}

Approach 2

By looking the production E->T , we may say that follow(T)=follow(E).

```
Here follow(T)={+}
```

So overall , follow(E)={$}  Union  {+}  = {+,$}.

Which approach is correct ?

And what is the Follow(E) ?

Answer (score 0):

To find follow set, we need to find the first set for non-terminals.

Here, first(T) = {i}, and first(E) = {i}

Considering first rule, i.e.  E -> T+E

follow(T) = first(+E)  i.e.  '+'

follow(E) = follow(E)

for rule E -> T

follow(T) = follow(E)

So, follow(E) = {$}, and follow(T) = {+, $}